# Filter Line and clustered column charts differently

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

So here is my line and clustered column chart. The ACT(blue) is the actual data which the user wants to compare to CF columns(current forecasts, dark blue). Lines are basically the same as the dark blue CF Columns, but in lines for better visuals. Filters: The left option would filter lines, the right option would filter the columns. So my plan is to let the users filter the columns and lines based on their needs. For example: User compares the ACT data(blue) and forecast(CF02 dark blue), but still wants to see the CF05, CF09(Line), and he/she wants to see less/more they could modify it to needs.

So in summary:
The left option would modify the dark blue columns, the rights options would filter the lines on the chart.

How do I manage to do this
On the attached GIF I present my attempt, but unfortunately dont work right. If its not the same CF, it simply blanks out.